# ¿Por qué no se actualiza p:datable dentro de p:dialog?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

El contenido de un componente `p:datatable` (listado de préstamos) que se encuentra dentro de un `p:dialog` no se refresca cuando presiono en el botón buscar.

Acá dejo la imagen.

- Nota: Estoy trabajando con primefaces version 6.1 .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista

```
        <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid width="900px" style="margin: 0 auto;background-color: #036fab;">
                    <p:commandButton value="Nuevo Pago" update="formFactura"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>

            <h:form id="formFactura">
                <p:panel header=".-." style="width: 900px; margin: 0 auto;text-align: center;">
                    <p:layout id="capaDatosClienteFactura" 
                              style="width: 100%;height: 250px;">
                        <p:layoutUnit id="datosCliente" position="center" 
                                      style="padding: 5px; text-align: justify;font-size: 14px;"
                                      size="300">
                            <h:panelGrid id="gridBuscarDatosCliente" columns="5">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Código Cliente" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                                <p:inputText id="txtCliente" size="12" value="#{prestamoController.cliente.idpersona}"/>
                                <p:commandButton value=".."  oncomplete="PF('dialogClientes').show();" 
                                                 update="formFactura dlgClientes">
                                    <p:ajax event="dialogReturn" listener="#{prestamoController.clienteSeleccionado}"
                                            process="@this" update="txtCliente"/>
                                </p:commandButton>


                                <p:outputLabel value="Fecha" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                                <p:outputLabel value="Fecha del Sistema" style="font-weight: bold;"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>
                            <!--SEPARAMOS-->
                            <p:separator/>
                            <h:panelGrid id="gridDatosCliente" columns="2">
                                <p:outputLabel value="Nombre" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                                <p:outputLabel id="lblNombre" value=""/>

                                <p:outputLabel value="DNI" style="font-weight: bold;"/>
                                <p:outputLabel id="lblDni" value=""/>


                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </p:layoutUnit>

                        <p:layoutUnit id="datosFactura" position="east" 
                                      style="padding: 5px; text-align: center;font-size: 14px;"
                                      size="200">
                            <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="font-size: 24px;font-weight: bold;margin-top: 30px;">
                                FACTURA
                                <p:outputLabel value="000001"/>

                            </h:panelGrid>

                        </p:layoutUnit>
                    </p:layout>
                    <p:separator/>
                    <!--GRID CUOTAS-->
                    <h:panelGrid id="gridBuscarCuota" columns="3">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Id Cuota  "/>
                        <p:inputText value="" size="12"/>
                        <p:commandButton value=".." oncomplete="PF('dialogCuotas').show();"
                                         update="formFactura:dlgCuotas"/>

                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <!--SEPARADOR-->
                    <p:separator/>
                    <!--TABLA DE FACTURA DE CUOTAS-->
                    <p:dataTable id="tablaCuotasFactura" emptyMessage="Aun no hay registros">
                        <p:column headerText="Nro Cuota">

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Valor">

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Vencimiento">

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Estado">

                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                    <!--Aqui mostramos los totales-->
                    <p:outputLabel value="TOTAL FACTURADO"/>
                    $<p:outputLabel value="Total a facturar"/>
                    <p:separator/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Registrar" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Imprimir" icon="ui-icon-print"/>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-close"/>

                </p:panel>

                <!--DIALOGO PARA MOSTRAR CLIENTES DEL SISTEMA-->

                <p:dialog id="dlgClientes"  widgetVar="dialogClientes" modal="true" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode"
                          appendTo="@(body)">

                    <p:dataTable id="tablaClientes" style="width: 700px;" paginator="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rows="5"
                                 value="#{clienteDataController.clienteList}"
                                 var="item"
                                 emptyMessage="No hay datos de clientes">
                        <!--Columnas-->
                        <p:column headerText="Id" style="text-align: center;width: 40px">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idpersona}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Cliente" style="text-align: left">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.apellido}, #{item.persona.nombre}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="DNI" style="width:20%;text-align: left">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.persona.numeroDocumento}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <!--Columna de Boton-->
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton  value="Seleccionar" 
                                              oncomplete="PF('dialogClientes').hide();"
                                              action="#{clienteDataController.seleccionarCliente(item)}"
                                              update="formFactura:gridDatosCliente"/>
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                    <!--Boton para cerrar-->
                    <p:commandButton value="Cerrar" onclick="PF('dialogClientes').hide();"/>

                </p:dialog>


                <!--DIALOGO PARA MOSTRAR cuotas DEL SISTEMA-->

                <p:dialog id="dlgCuotas"  widgetVar="dialogCuotas" modal="true" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode"
                          appendTo="@(body)" closeOnEscape="true">

                    <!--Campos de busqueda por Apellido y DNI-->

                    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
                        <p:outputLabel for="seleccion" value="Buscar por:" />
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="seleccion" value="#{consultarController.opcionSeleccionada}" 
                                          converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Apellido" itemValue="1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dni" itemValue="2" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                        <p:inputText id="txtBusqueda" value="#{consultarController.valorBusqueda}">
                            <p:ajax event="keyup" update="formFactura:tablaPrestamo"/>
                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" value="Buscar" update="formFactura:tablaPrestamo"
                                         actionListener="#{consultarController.buscarPor()}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <p:separator/>

                    <!--TABLA DE PRESTAMOS-->

                    <p:dataTable id="tablaPrestamo" 
                                 style="width: 700px;"
                                 resizableColumns="true"
                                 scrollable="true" 
                                 scrollWidth="800"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rows="3"
                                 value="#{consultarController.prestamos}" 
                                 var="p"
                                 rowKey="#{p.idprestamo}"
                                 selectionMode="single"
                                 selection="#{consultarController.selected}"

                                 emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros "
                                 rendered="true"
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{consultarController.prestamoSeleccionado}" />

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Listado de Préstamos
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column style="width:3%; text-align:left;" sortBy="#{p.idprestamo}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cód."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idprestamo}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Monto"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.montoprestado}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha Sol."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.fechaSolicitud}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cuotas"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.cantidadCuotas}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="TNA %"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.tna}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Gastos Adm."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.gastosAdm}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Seg"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.seguroVida}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="IVA %"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.iva}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cliente"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idpersona.persona.apellido},#{p.idpersona.persona.nombre}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Estado"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idestadoprestamo.descripcion}"/>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                              title="Ver Detalle"
                                              update="formFactura:tablaCuota"
                                              />
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>
                    <p:separator/>

                    <!--LIstado de Cuotas-->

                    <p:dataTable id="tablaCuota" style="width: 700px;" paginator="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rows="3"
                                 value="#{consultarController.selected.cuotaCollection}"
                                 var="item"
                                 emptyMessage="No hay datos de cuotas">
                        <!--Columnas-->
                        <p:column headerText="Nro. Cuota" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nroCuota}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Valor" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.valorCuota}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Vencimiento">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaVenc}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyy"/>
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Estado">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idestadocuota}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <!--Columna de Boton-->
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton  value="Seleccionar" 
                                              oncomplete="PF('dialogCuotas').hide();"
                                              />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                    <!--Boton para cerrar-->
                    <p:commandButton value="Cerrar" onclick="PF('dialogCuotas').hide();"/>

                </p:dialog>

            </h:form>
```

Bean

```
public class ConsultarController implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ClienteFacade clienteFacade;
@Inject
private PrestamoFacade prestamoFacade;
@Inject
private GestorImpresion gestorImpresion;
@Inject
ResourcesFiles rf;
@Inject
private PagoFacade pagoFacade;
@Inject
private CuotaFacade cuotaFacade;

private List<Cliente> clientes;
private List<Prestamo> prestamos;
private ArrayList<Cuota> lista = new ArrayList<Cuota>() {
};
private String valorBusqueda;
private int opcionSeleccionada;

private Prestamo selected;
private Cuota seleccion;
private Cuota filaSeleccionada;
private int cuotaId;
private int dias;
private double valorDeRecargo;
// Aqui agregue
Estadocuota estadoCuota;

private Pago pago;

public int getCuotaId() {
    return cuotaId;
}

public ArrayList<Cuota> getLista() {
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(ArrayList<Cuota> lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}

public void setCuotaId(int cuotaId) {
    this.cuotaId = cuotaId;
}
private HtmlDataTable tabla;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    clientes = clienteFacade.findAll();
    selected = new Prestamo();
    estadoCuota = new Estadocuota();
    valorDeRecargo = 0;
    iniciar();
}

/**
 * Metodo que permite mostrar el listado de los usuarios al momento de
 * inicar
 */
public void iniciar() {
    prestamos = prestamoFacade.obtenerListaDePrestamos();

}

public void seleccionLista() {
    filaSeleccionada = (Cuota) tabla.getRowData();
    this.cuotaId = filaSeleccionada.getIdcuota();
}

public Cuota getSeleccion() {
    return seleccion;
}

public void setSeleccion(Cuota seleccion) {
    this.seleccion = seleccion;
}

public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
    return clientes;
}

public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
    this.clientes = clientes;
}

public List<Prestamo> getPrestamos() {
    return prestamos;
}

public void setPrestamos(List<Prestamo> prestamos) {
    this.prestamos = prestamos;
}

public String getValorBusqueda() {
    return valorBusqueda;
}

public void setValorBusqueda(String valorBusqueda) {
    this.valorBusqueda = valorBusqueda;
}

public int getOpcionSeleccionada() {
    return opcionSeleccionada;
}

public void setOpcionSeleccionada(int opcionSeleccionada) {
    this.opcionSeleccionada = opcionSeleccionada;
}

public Prestamo getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Prestamo selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public HtmlDataTable getTabla() {
    return tabla;
}

public void setTabla(HtmlDataTable tabla) {
    this.tabla = tabla;
}

public void buscarPrestamos() {
    try {
        prestamos = prestamoFacade.buscarPrestamo(valorBusqueda);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void buscarPor() {
    switch (opcionSeleccionada) {
        case 1:
            try {
                prestamos = prestamoFacade.findByApellidoLike(valorBusqueda);
                valorBusqueda = "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            try {
                prestamos = prestamoFacade.buscarPrestamo(valorBusqueda);
                valorBusqueda = "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw e;
            }
            break;

    }

}

public String imprimir() {
    String ruta = "/resources/reportes/newReport.jasper";
    HashMap parameters = new HashMap();

    //parameters.put("fecha", fecha);
    //Date fecha = new Date(2017, 5, 13);
    //parameters.put("fecha", fecha);
    gestorImpresion.imprimir(prestamoFacade.obtenerListaDePrestamos(), ruta, parameters);
    return null;
}

/**
 * Método que nos permite abrir un cuadro de dialogo para buscar clientes
 */
public void abrirDialogo() {
    //Logica -- Aqui podemos validar "Algo" antes de abrir el cuadro de dilogo

    int estadoPrestamo = selected.getIdestadoprestamo().getIdestadoprestamo();
    switch (estadoPrestamo) {
        case 1:
            Map<String, Object> opciones = new HashMap<>();
            opciones.put("modal", true);
            //Evita la redimension del cuadro de dialogo
            opciones.put("resizable", false);
            //Dimension de alto
            opciones.put("contentHeight", 470);
            // Le pasamos los parametros Nombre de pagina, opciones 
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/faces/pages/cuota/cuotalist.xhtml", opciones, null);
            break;
        case 2:
            JSFUtil.addWarningMessage("El préstamo, ya se encuentra cancelado");
            break;
        case 3:
            JSFUtil.addErrorMessage("El préstamo aun no esta activo. Por favor pase por caja para cobrarlo");
            break;
        default:
            JSFUtil.addErrorMessage("Opcion no valida.");
    }

}

// Lo que podemos hacer es traer la coleccion seleccionada
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Cuota Seleccionada", "Código: " + ((Cuota) event.getObject()).getIdcuota().toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

/**
 * Este metodo funciona la perfeccion primero pago la cuota y luego la
 * actualizo
 *
 * @
 */
public void pagar() {
    int estado = seleccion.getIdprestamo().getIdestadoprestamo().getIdestadoprestamo();
    switch (estado) {
        case 1:
            pagarCreditoActivo();

            // Aqui deberiamos cerrar el dialogo
            break;
        case 2:
            JSFUtil.addErrorMessage("El credito está Cancelado");
            break;
        case 3:
            JSFUtil.addWarningMessage("El credito se encuentra en caja");
            break;

    }

}

// Lo que podemos hacer es traer la coleccion seleccionada
public void prestamoSeleccionado(SelectEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Préstamo Seleccionado", "Código: " + ((Prestamo) event.getObject()).getIdprestamo().toString());
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

// Tengo que hacer mas modulos para el metodo pagar
public String pagarCreditoActivo() {
    try {
        pago = new Pago();
        // Antes de Pagar debo controlar que el credito este activo
        //que la cuota no este pagada y si
        // tiene recargo o  no
        // si esta pagada mandar mensaje de error
        // si no esta pagada pagar.
        if (seleccion.getIdestadocuota().getIdestadocuota() != 1) {
            // La cuota no esta pagada
            // la cuota tendra recargo por mora ?
            if (seleccion.getIdestadocuota().getIdestadocuota() == 3) {
                //Calculamos el interes del 1 % del valor de la cuota
                //Por cada dia de retraso debo calcular la mora
                dias = (int) ((JSFUtil.getFechaActual().getTime() - seleccion.getFechaVenc().getTime()) / 86400000);
                //Obtengo el 1% del valor de la cuota como recargo
                valorDeRecargo = (((seleccion.getValorCuota().doubleValue()) * 0.01) * dias);
                // Asigno el recargo al pago
                pago.setRecargoPorMora(BigDecimal.valueOf(valorDeRecargo));

            } else {
                pago.setRecargoPorMora(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0));
            }
            // Debems convertir los valores
            pago.setMontoAbonado(BigDecimal.valueOf(seleccion.getValorCuota().doubleValue() + valorDeRecargo));

            // Aqui se corta. pago = null la seleccion sigue teniendo la 
            // cuota 199
            pago.setIdcuota(seleccion);
            pago.setFechaDePago(JSFUtil.getFechaActual());
            pagoFacade.create(pago);
            // Aqui tmb se clava por que no eh creado el objeto estadoCuota
            estadoCuota.setIdestadocuota(1);
            seleccion.setIdestadocuota(estadoCuota);
            //Deberia ACTUALIZAR LA CUOTA COMO PAGADA
            cuotaFacade.edit(seleccion);

            JSFUtil.addSuccessMessage(rf.getMensajeArb("info.update"));
            //iniciar();
            pago = new Pago();
            estadoCuota = new Estadocuota();
            seleccion = new Cuota();

        } else {
            // Entonces la cuota esta pagada y debo salir
            JSFUtil.addErrorMessage("La cuota ya esta pagada");
            return null;

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JSFUtil.addErrorMessage(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

¿Alguien sabe en qué estoy fallando?

Answer (score 1):

Ya encontré la solución . Comparto el código, tal vez alguien tenga el mismo problema y lo necesite.

Saludos.

```
<!-- ========================================================================= -->
            <!-- =======================DIALOGO PRESTAMOS Y CUOTAS ======================= -->
            <!-- ========================================================================= -->


            <p:dialog id="dlgCuotas"  widgetVar="dialogCuotas" modal="true" resizable="false" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode"
                      appendTo="@(body)" closeOnEscape="true">

                <!--Campos de busqueda por Apellido y DNI-->
                <h:form id="dlgFormPrestamo">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
                        <p:outputLabel for="seleccion" value="Buscar por:" />
                        <p:selectOneRadio id="seleccion" value="#{consultarController.opcionSeleccionada}" 
                                          converter="javax.faces.Integer">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Apellido" itemValue="1" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dni" itemValue="2" />
                        </p:selectOneRadio>
                        <p:inputText id="txtBusqueda" value="#{consultarController.valorBusqueda}">

                        </p:inputText>
                        <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-search" value="Buscar" 
                                         action="#{consultarController.buscarPor()}"
                                         update="tablaPrestamo"
                                         />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <p:separator/>

                    <!-- ========================================================================= -->
                    <!-- ======================= TABLA PRESTAMOS ================================= -->
                    <!-- ========================================================================= -->


                    <p:dataTable id="tablaPrestamo" 
                                 style="width: 700px;"
                                 resizableColumns="true"
                                 scrollable="true" 
                                 scrollWidth="800"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rows="3"
                                 value="#{consultarController.prestamos}" 
                                 var="p"
                                 rowKey="#{p.idprestamo}"
                                 selectionMode="single"
                                 selection="#{consultarController.selected}"

                                 emptyMessage="No se encontraron registros "
                                 rendered="true"
                                 >
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{consultarController.prestamoSeleccionado}" />

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Listado de Préstamos
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column style="width:3%; text-align:left;" sortBy="#{p.idprestamo}">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cód."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idprestamo}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Monto"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.montoprestado}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Fecha Sol."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.fechaSolicitud}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cuotas"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.cantidadCuotas}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="TNA %"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.tna}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Gastos Adm."/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.gastosAdm}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Seg"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.seguroVida}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column style="width:4%; text-align:center;">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="IVA %"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.iva}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column >
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Cliente"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idpersona.persona.apellido},#{p.idpersona.persona.nombre}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Estado"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.idestadoprestamo.descripcion}"/>

                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                              title="Ver Detalle"
                                              update=":dlgFormPrestamo:tablaCuota"
                                              />
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>

                    <p:separator/>


                    <!-- ========================================================================= -->
                    <!-- =======================TABLA COLECCION DE CUOTAS ========================== -->
                    <!-- ========================================================================= -->


                    <p:dataTable id="tablaCuota" style="width: 700px;" paginator="true"
                                 paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rows="3"
                                 value="#{consultarController.selected.cuotaCollection}"
                                 var="item"
                                 emptyMessage="No hay datos de cuotas">
                        <!--Columnas-->
                        <p:column headerText="Id. Cuota" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idcuota}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Nro. Cuota" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.nroCuota}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Valor" >
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.valorCuota}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Vencimiento">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.fechaVenc}">
                                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyy"/>
                            </h:outputText>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Estado">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.idestadocuota}"/>
                        </p:column>
                        <!--Columna de Boton-->
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton  value="Seleccionar" actionListener="#{factura.agregarCuotasAtabla2(item.idcuota)}"
                                              oncomplete="PF('dialogCuotas').hide();"
                                              update=":formFactura:tablaCuotasFactura"
                                              />
                        </p:column>

                    </p:dataTable>
                    <!--Boton para cerrar-->
                    <p:commandButton value="Cerrar" onclick="PF('dialogCuotas').hide();"/>
                </h:form>
            </p:dialog>
```

Comment: Es bueno explicar cuales fueron los cambios que hiciste, tal vez ayude a alguien.